# Magento2 Graphql get select attribute options label instead of option id

Tags: product-attribute, graphql, select, attribute-options

I am using v2.4 in which in the **products** query I am getting the **Optionid** of select attribute instead of attribute option label.
Like if i try to get **color**(select type) then I get value of red instead of label **Red**

So anybody can help me get the label instead of id

Here is my sample code

```
query {
 products(search:"test", pageSize: 15, sort: {price: DESC}) {
  total_count
  items {
    name
    sku
    color
    price_range {
      minimum_price {
        regular_price {
          value
          currency
        }
      }
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: [Try this](https://github.com/theshreyas/magento-2-quickies/tree/main/GraphQl/DynamicAttributesGraphql)

Answer (score 1):

You can also find the attribute option label by searching the attribute option ID with https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/custom-attribute-metadata.html